# Windows Install Management

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, ssd, storage, windows-installation

I got a **1TB SSD** (Samsung 850 EVO) today, and also have **250 GB SSD** where my Windows is installed.

So my question is should I move my Windows install to the new 1TB SSD or leave it on the 250 GB SSD?

I ask this as I want to dual boot Windows and Ubuntu, and have enough space for doing Machine Learning on Ubuntu.

**Also,**
Would there be any advantage to moving the install to the bigger SSD?

Comment: If you want your system disk to be the TB SSD, clone the 250 GB to the 1 TB SSD, then extend the system partition to use the unallocated space.

Comment: Wow learn something new every day! Didn't know you could combine two SSDs together. I knew you could split a SSD

Comment: You are not combining two SDDs together just clonning a drive to another drive then getting rid of the other drive